# How can I smooth the edges?

Tags: modeling, edges

The first picture uses the sub modification. the second is its original form.I just want the edges to be soft and cylindrical.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try that: right click and Shade Smooth, then in the Properties panel > Object Data > Normals, enable Auto-Smooth. It will smooth the surface, not the edges though

Comment: omg thank u it worked!!! <3